# SSRS Report Builder only increment RowNumber on visible rows

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am using Report builder for the first time ever and I am trying to hide every other row on an ssrs report. The tool Im using wont allow me to render 2 columns with Report Builder so I am trying to fake it by duplicating my table and hiding every other row.

I currently hide rows if a certain row doesn't contain a string. And now I need to make report builder hide every other row of the remaining unhidden rows.

I cannot seem to wrap my head around how the function syntax works in each section of the group properties.

EDIT:
modified sql

SELECT
T2.Comment,
T1.PartNum,
T2.Qty
FROM Part
WHERE T2.Comment <> ''

Comment: would be way easier to do this in the dataset - do you use SQL or the likes for your datasource?

Comment: I will try to figure this out, I don't have much experience with SQL either, I was sort of dropped into some data reporting type work in my engineering job today.

Comment: put up some sample data and which rows you want to hide.. we may be able to help you with the SQL

Comment: I basically just want to hide every row where the comment is an empty string, and then after that just hide every other row on one table, and the opposite on the other table.

Comment: Im trying to add a WHERE T.comment != "" at the end of my SELECT

Comment: show and tell is easier for us to understand the problem than just trying to describe what you want..